# SP 2010 - Lookup Column not working with Conditional Formatting

Tags: list, lookup-column, formatting, conditional

I have a lookup column for Tabs:

Major
Sub-1
Sub-2
Sub-3
Technical
Pricing

I need to setup conditional formatting so the row color changes with the level of tab selected. I can do this with drop down columns, but it is not working with lookup?

Is there a work around for this? If not how do I have a drop down that will not give me an error if there is no blank option?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup column data is stored in format `ID:#stringvalue`. Hence if you do an `equal` comparison, it will fail.

The best option is to use `contains`